# Understanding the MonadIO Laws

Tags: haskell

From [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.IO.Class.html#MonadIO):

```
module Control.Monad.IO.Class (
    MonadIO(..)
  ) where

-- | Monads in which 'IO' computations may be embedded.
-- Any monad built by applying a sequence of monad transformers to the
-- 'IO' monad will be an instance of this class.
--
-- Instances should satisfy the following laws, which state that 'liftIO'
-- is a transformer of monads:
--
-- * @'liftIO' . 'return' = 'return'@
--
-- * @'liftIO' (m >>= f) = 'liftIO' m >>= ('liftIO' . f)@

class (Monad m) => MonadIO m where
    -- | Lift a computation from the 'IO' monad.
    liftIO :: IO a -> m a

instance MonadIO IO where
    liftIO = id
```

What is meant by

> ```
> liftIO (m >>= f) = liftIO m >>= (liftIO . f)
> ```

And in particular, what is meant by `(m >>= f)`? Here `m` is a function on types and `f` a function on values. So isn't that notation non-sense?

Comment: `m` isn't the `m` from the type signature, but a monadic action of type `m a`.

Comment: Those are literally just the `MonadTrans` laws adapted for `liftIO` instead of `lift`.

Comment: `>>=` is a function as well http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-

Comment: The variable `m` is not the one in the signature. Does this alpha-equivalent reformulation help: `liftIO (x >>= f) = liftIO x >>= (liftIO . f)`?

Comment: Or, another way to say what everybody else is saying: there is an implicit quantification at the beginning of the law; strictly speaking, it should say `forall m. forall f. liftIO (m >>= f) = liftIO m >>= liftIO . f`. This is generally the case for typeclass laws: any identifiers which are not methods of the class (or its superclasses) are implicitly universally quantified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the `m` in the law is just a value variable, and is not the same `m` as the type variable `m` used in the `class` definition.

If you rewrite the law as:

```
liftIO (act >>= f) = liftIO act >>= (liftIO . f)
```

equivalent to:

```
liftIO $ do x <- act     ===      do x <- liftIO act
            f x                      liftIO (f x)
```

with the understanding that `act` is an IO action, then it may be clearer what's going on.  The expression `act >>= f` represents the composite IO action that, when run, will run the IO action `act` and pass its return value to `f` to generate a new IO action (say `act2`) that will then be run.

The law just says that lifting this composite IO action into a different monad creates an action that, when run, is equivalent running a lifted version of `act`, passing its return value to `f` to generate a new IO action, lifting that action to the other monad, and running that.

As a concrete example, `getLine >>= print` is the IO action that reads a line and then prints its value in Haskell string syntax.  The law says that you can either lift this directly into another monad:

```
liftIO $ do x <- getLine
            print x
```

to get an action that does that, or you can lift the IO action parts separately:

```
do x <- liftIO getLine
   liftIO (print x)
```

and get exactly the same action.